# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found in VScode

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, nltk

I am using virtual environment. Also activated the virtual environment in vs code but still facing the import error DLL load failed . This is for NLTK module and sqlite3. Please help me to resolve this.